# Relationship between mono-, epi- and isomorphisms in Category Theory

Tags: category-theory

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ba_hon70qbg) defines mono- and epimorphisms this way:

- $f: a \to b$ is a monomorphism if $f \circ g = f \circ h \Longrightarrow g = h \; \forall g, h: c \to a$ (i.e. $f$ is left-cancelable)
- $f: a \to b$ is an epimorphism if $g \circ f = h \circ f \Longrightarrow g = h \; \forall g, h: b \to c$ (i.e. it is right-cancelable)

**Q1:** Is there a reason why the implications between equalities and equalities when composed with $f$ are not coimplications?

The video goes on saying that $f: a \to b$ is an isomorphism if $\exists f^{-1}: b \to a \;\mid\; f^{-1}\circ f = id_a \land f \circ f^{-1} = id_B$

**Q2:** Is there some relationship between $f$ being both mono- and epi- and it being an isomorphism?
One might naively go ahead and try to say for example that, if $f$ is an isomorphism
$$\forall g, h: c \to a, \quad f \circ g = f \circ h \Longrightarrow f^{-1} \circ f \circ g = f^{-1} \circ f \circ g \Longrightarrow id_A \circ g = id_A \circ h \Longrightarrow g = h$$
But step 1 assumes $f^{-1}$ to be left-cancelable, which is implied by $f$ being left-cancelable in the other sense of the implication, proof:
$$f \circ g = f \circ h \Longrightarrow g = h \\
\Downarrow \\
f \circ f^{-1} \circ g = f \circ f^{-1} \circ h \Longrightarrow f \circ g = f \circ h \\
\Downarrow \\
g = h \Longrightarrow f \circ g = f \circ h$$
So the above attempt to prove that $f$ is mono- if it is iso- depends on it being mono- (if the previous question has answer "no"). The epi- counterpart of this reasoning is trivial.
Consider that I managed to follow the video only up to the functors definition.

Comment: The converse implications are trivial, aren't they?

Comment: yes, the converse implications are true for any $f$

Comment: I don't know, CT confuses me so much that when things feel trivial I'm afraid my reasoning is not abstract enough...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Q1: the reverse implications are trivial.

Q2: an isomorphism is necessarily mono and epi. The converse is not true in general categories. For instance, the embedding of $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Q}$ is mono and epi in the category of rings, but it's clearly not an isomorphism.

On the positive side: in an abelian category, a morphism that's both mono and epi is an isomorphism.

Why is an isomorphism a mono? The idea is exactly the one you had, but inserting $f^{-1}$ in the right place: suppose $f$ is an isomorphism and that
$$
f \circ g = f \circ h
$$
Then also
$$
f^{-1}\circ(f \circ g) = f^{-1}\circ(f \circ h)
$$
and, by associativity,
$$
(f^{-1}\circ f) \circ g = (f^{-1}\circ f) \circ h
$$
giving
$$
\mathit{id}_a\circ g=\mathit{id}_a\circ h
$$
and, finally, $g=h$.

The proof that an isomorphism is epi is dual.

Comment: Thanks, could you include proof?

Comment: @Glaedr Added (about Q2).

Comment: How is the first step granted to be true?

Comment: @Glaedr Basic property of the identity morphism?

Comment: So where am I wrong in the and of my question?

Comment: @Glaedr The line after “$f$ is an isomorphism” is basically the same as my (just more detailed) proof. The rest is meaningless, I'm afraid.

Comment: I mean, isn't the fact that you could add $f^{-1}$ to both sides and still maintain the equality a property of monomorphisms?

Comment: @Glaedr No. Not at all: $f^{-1}$ is only defined for an isomorphism.

Comment: I mean $f^{-1}$ being a morphism like any other, doesn't being able to compose it to the left of both sides and still hold the equality require it to be a monomorphism?

Comment: @Glaedr I'm not sure to understand; the proof that an isomorphism is mono ends when you reach $g=h$ in the first line.

Comment: I am talking about the step from the first to the second equality.

Comment: @Glaedr Sorry, but I don't understand: if $u=v$, then it's obvious that $w\circ u=w\circ v$.

Comment: Ok, I had to scribble a discrete category to figure it out but now I see it: it's the other way around that is non-trivial. Thanks for your time.

Comment: *finite category

Answer (score 3):

For $Q1$, the converse is avoided because it is trivially true for all $g,h$.

Q2: It is obviously true that every isomorphism is epi and mono, but the converse is not true. Take the category formed from a poset[*], where $\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$ always has at most one element. When $\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)$ can never have more than one element, every morphism is epi and mono trivially, because every $g,h:c\to a$ are necessarily equal. However, in the category for a poset, the only morphisms with inverses are the indentities, where $X=Y$.

[*] Given any poset (partially ordered set,) $(P,\leq)$, you can define a category with objects $X\in P$, and with $$\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)=\begin{cases}\{\star_{X,Y}\}&X\leq Y\\
\emptyset &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
with $\star_{Y,Z}\circ\star_{X,Y} = \star_{X,Z}$.

One of the conditions of a poset is that if $X\leq Y$ and $Y\leq X$ then $X=Y$. That shows that the only isomorphisms are the identities.